# PHP Tree Nested set to Multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, treeview, nested

I am having a little problem i need some help with. Need to convert the PHP Nested Tree structure in the array

```
$array = {
     array(
       'id' => 1,
       'name' => 'john'
       'left' => '1'
       'right' => '4'
     ),
     array(
       'id' => 2,
       'name' => 'jane'
       'left' => '2'
       'right' => '3'
     )
}
```

TO

```
$array = array(
     'id' => 1,
     'name' => 'john',
     'childs' => array(
         array(
             'id' => 2,
             'name' => 'jane'
         )
      )        
)
```

Here is the Tree architecture.

http://fuelphp.com/docs/packages/orm/model/nestedset.html

I need like parent child array

Comment: What determines the array `jane` is a child of `john`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
If left and right keys represent indexes in $array then:

$out = array();

foreach ($array as $index => $data) {
      $storeKey = sprintf("%s_%s", $data['id'], $data['name']);
      $keysToCopy = array('id', 'name');

      if(!isset($out[$storeKey])){
            $out[$storeKey] = array_merge(
                  array_intersect_key($data, array_flip($keysToCopy)), 
                  array("childs" => array())
                  );
      }

      $check = array('left', 'right');

      foreach ($check as $checkChild) {
            if(isset($array[$data[$checkChild]])){
                  $child = array_intersect_key($array[$data[$checkChild]], array_flip($keysToCopy));
                  $out[$storeKey]['childs'][] = $child;
            }

      }
}

$out = array_values($out);

var_dump($out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if it is just the array you posted:

```
$newArray = array(
   'id' => $oldArray[0]['id'],
   'name' => $oldArray[0]['name'],
   'childs' => array( 
     'id' => $oldArray[1]['id'],
     'name' => $oldArray[1]['name']
   )
);
```

If you need it in a loop you'll need to provide some more information. As in the comments already mentioned what determines that jane is a child of john?